# Do some action onPreferenceChange

Tags: android, kotlin

I can't force Android Studio to compile this. After four days of googling have less knowledge then before... I understand, that something is wrong with  setOnPreferenceChangeListener parameter but what?

```
class MessagesFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        private val TAG = "MF"
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.messages_preferences, rootKey)

            val sw1 = findPreference<SwitchPreference>("switchButton1")
            sw1?.setOnPreferenceChangeListener({ _ ,  isChecked ->
                val message = if (isChecked) "Switch1:ON" else "Switch1:OFF"
                Log.d(TAG, message)

            })
        }
    }
```

I simply want to see SWITCH1:ON or :OFF in the log....

But `Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Boolean was expected`

Answer (score 2):

OnPreferenceChangeListener is [supposed to return a Boolean](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener). The last line of your lambda must evaluate to either true or false. If you make it false, it will reject the preference change, and the value will remain unchanged even though the user clicked it. In most cases, you'll just want to put true.

```
        sw1?.setOnPreferenceChangeListener { _ ,  isChecked ->
            val message = if (isChecked) "Switch1:ON" else "Switch1:OFF"
            Log.d(TAG, message)
            true
        }
```

The reason the error message was talking about inferring Unit is that functions that return nothing implicitly return Unit in Kotlin. The last line of your lambda was calling `Log.d()`, which implicitly returns Unit.

Comment: Better (now it is compiling), but Lambda argument should be moved out of parathenses... (still nothing in log)

Comment: You might try asserting non-null `sw1!!` to be sure it's actually finding your preference. Not sure what you're saying about the parentheses. I removed them in my code because they are unnecessary and it's conventional to omit parentheses around a single lambda parameter in Kotlin.

Comment: It looks your're right! But why it can't find the preference (android:id was copied... Very strange

Comment: DAMN IT!!! If I use findPreference I should use KEY instead of ID!!!! Many thanks!

Comment: Don't pass the name of the ID, pass the value of the `android:key`.